# How to change initial screen in Route.Js with Async Storage in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I am trying to change the entrance point my application in Router.js to not show the user Onboarding screens second time. Basically I set an async storage value. When the onboarding is finished the value return true. As the async storage functions are async, the return statement in Router.js is not waiting the it to return a value. So I can’t change the initial point of my navigation system.

**index.js**

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Router);
```

**Router.js**

```
function Router() {

let first ="App"
let second ="GetStarted"



  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={checkFirstUsage().then(data=>data?second:first)} screenOptions={{headerShown: false} }>
        <Stack.Screen name="GetStarted" component={GetStarted} />
        <Stack.Screen name="EnterPoem" component={EnterPoem} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Interest" component={Interested} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Begin" component={Begin} />
        <Stack.Screen name="App" component={App} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}
```

**checkFirstUsage**

```
const checkFirstUsage = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@isAsyncStorageSet')
      if(value === null) {
      
      return true
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach when you want to manage separated stack navigators is something like

### index.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import OnBoardingRoutes from './onBoarding.routes';
import AppRoutes from './app.routes';
import checkFirstUsage from "./checkFirstUsage/path";


const Routes: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [firstUsage,setFirstUsage] =useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
     async function check() {
          const fU = await checkFirstUsage()
          setFirstUsage(fU)
          setLoading(false)
     }

     check()
  },[])

  if (loading) return null  // or any better component

  return firstUsage ? <OnBoardingRoutes /> : <AppRoutes />;
};

export default Routes;
```

And then you have your two stacks navigator, with their respective routes

### onBoarding.routes

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import OnBoardingPage1 from '../pages/OnBoardingPage1';
import OnBoardingPage2 from '../pages/OnBoardingPage2';


const App = createStackNavigator();

const OnBoardingRoutes: React.FC = () => (
  <App.Navigator
    initialRouteName="GetStarted"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}
  >
    <App.Screen name="OnBoardingPage1" component={OnBoardingPage1} />
    <App.Screen name="OnBoardingPage2" component={OnBoardingPage2} />

  </App.Navigator>
);

export default OnBoardingRoutes;
```

and your App routes

### app.routes

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import AppPage1 from '../pages/AppPage1';
    import AppPage2 from '../pages/AppPage2';

    
    const App = createStackNavigator();
    
    const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => (
      <App.Navigator
        initialRouteName="App"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <App.Screen name="AppPage1" component={AppPage1} />
        <App.Screen name="AppPage2" component={AppPage2} />

      </App.Navigator>
    );
    
    export default AppRoutes;
```

and your **Router**  component will looks like

```
import React from "react"
import Routes from "./index";


    function Router() {
    
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
           <Routes/>
        </NavigationContainer>
        
      );
    }
export default Router;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With your answer, the problem has disappeared completely :))

Comment: Happy to help! My first right answer here :)

Comment: Congratulations :). From now on, I will be following your other answers.